# What is bundling my rollup project when it's a dependency of another project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, rollupjs

I'm trying to create a React Website using 2 projects:

- React-kit to store a list a components
- React-app who run the React server (and have React-kit as dependency)

I mostly followed [this tutorial](https://medium.com/grandata-engineering/how-i-set-up-a-react-component-library-with-rollup-be6ccb700333) to build my React-kit using [Rollup](https://github.com/rollup/rollup) (and [babel](https://babeljs.io/)).

I put React-Kit as dependency into my React-App using private github repository: (I added all my building files (rollup, babel and webpack for both projects) at the end of the questions if needed.)

**package.json**

```
{
  /* ... */
  "dependencies": {
    "react-kit": "github:myUser/react-Kit",  
    /* ... */
  }
}
```

**First at all** it's working fine on local, and it's a big question for me? Who did the job for it ?

During my research I notice:

- `dist/` is **not** present in React-Kit github repository (but `src/` is here)
- `dist/` is present on my local `React-App/node_modules/react-kit/` (with only `package*.json`, **not** `src/`)
- When I do my `npm i` on React-App the React-kit is downloaded (that part i understand ^^) then bundled by his rollup config file.

How my react-kit has been bundled ? Who did the call the start rollup when I did my `npm i` on React-App ??

**Second** I tying to deploy the React-App project on production using Jenkins, but in this case 
my react-kit/dist is not here and `React-App/node_modules/react-kit` only have `package*.json` (so my react-app build fail because `react-kit` cannot be imported).

What's going on here ? I trying with both env (dev and prod) on both local and AWS but it's always the same things.

I think I'm missing something here..

---

#### React-kit

**rollup.config.js**

```
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel'
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs'
import external from 'rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external'
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss'
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve'
import url from 'rollup-plugin-url'
import svgr from '@svgr/rollup'
import { terser } from 'rollup-plugin-terser'

import pkg from './package.json'

export default {
  input: 'src/lib/index.js',
  output: [
    {
      file: pkg.main,
      format: 'cjs',
      sourcemap: true,
    },
    {
      file: pkg.module,
      format: 'es',
      sourcemap: true,
    },
  ],
  plugins: [
    external({
      // includeDependencies: true,
    }),
    postcss({
      plugins: [],
      minimize: true,
      sourceMap: 'inline',
    }),
    url(),
    svgr(),
    resolve(),
    babel({
      plugins: [
        '@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread',
        '@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining',
        '@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import',
        '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
        'transform-react-remove-prop-types',
      ],
      exclude: 'node_modules/**',
    }),
    commonjs(),
    // terser(),    // Activate to minimify
  ],
}
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "modules": false
      }
    ],
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "presets": [
        [
          "react-app"
        ]
      ]
    }
  },
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
  ]
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "react-kit",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "React components dictionary for Projects",
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "module": "dist/index.es.js",
  "jsnext:main": "dist/index.es.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=8",
    "npm": ">=5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "run-p build:watch start",
    "start": "styleguidist server --open",
    "styleguide:build": "styleguidist build",
    "build": "rollup -c",
    "build:watch": "rollup -c -w",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:coverage": "jest --coverage --forceExit --colors",
    "lint": "esw --ext .jsx --ext .js --color",
    "lint:fix": "npm run lint --fix",
    "prepare": "npm run build",
    "prerelease": "npm run lint:fix && npm run test:coverage && npm run build",
    "release": "npm publish",
    "predeploy": "npm run styleguide:build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d styleguide"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "formik": "^1.5.8"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.4",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.5.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.5.4",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.5.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "@svgr/rollup": "^4.3.1",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.2",
    "babel-jest": "^24.8.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types": "^0.4.24",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^9.0.0",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.10.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.14.0",
    "eslint": "^6.0.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^3.11.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.18.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^22.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.14.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^1.6.1",
    "eslint-watch": "^5.1.2",
    "gh-pages": "^2.0.1",
    "jasmine-expect": "^4.0.2",
    "jest": "^24.8.0",
    "jest-pnp-resolver": "^1.2.1",
    "jest-resolve": "^24.8.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^1.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
    "react-styleguidist": "^9.1.11",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.8.6",
    "rollup": "^1.16.7",
    "rollup-plugin-babel": "^4.3.3",
    "rollup-plugin-commonjs": "^10.0.1",
    "rollup-plugin-node-resolve": "^5.2.0",
    "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external": "^2.2.0",
    "rollup-plugin-postcss": "^2.0.3",
    "rollup-plugin-terser": "^5.1.1",
    "rollup-plugin-url": "^2.2.2",
    "webpack": "^4.35.3",
    "webpack-blocks": "^2.0.1"
  },
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "!src/**/*.d.ts",
      "!src/**/index.js"
    ],
    "resolver": "jest-pnp-resolver",
    "setupFiles": [
      "react-app-polyfill/jsdom",
      "<rootDir>/scripts/enzymeConfig.js"
    ],
    "testMatch": [
      "**/__tests__/**/*.[jt]s?(x)",
      "**/?(*.)+(spec|test).[jt]s?(x)"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
    "testURL": "http://localhost",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/scripts/cssTransform.js",
      "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/scripts/fileTransform.js"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$",
      "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$"
    ],
    "moduleDirectories": [
      "node_modules",
      "src"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^react-native$": "react-native-web",
      "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "web.js",
      "js",
      "web.ts",
      "ts",
      "web.tsx",
      "tsx",
      "json",
      "web.jsx",
      "jsx",
      "node"
    ]
  }
}
```

#### React-App

**webpack.config.js**

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');

const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

const config = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new Dotenv({
      path: `.env.${env !== 'development' ? env : ''}`,
    })
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.m?js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'less-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [
      '.js',
      '.jsx'
    ]
  }
}

module.exports = config;
```

**babel.config.js**

```
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    "presets": [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      "@babel/preset-react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
    ]
  }
};
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "modules": false
      },
      "@babel/preset-react'"
    ],
  ],
  "plugins": [
    ["@babel/transform-runtime"]
  ]
}
```

Comment: Have you scripts in package.json of React-kit?

Comment: @Troopers, yes a lots.. I updated my answer to add react-kit package.json

Comment: React-kit is a peerDependency or dependency of React-app?

Comment: It's a dependency

Comment: in your `rollup.config.js` file, your `output` should be `file: 'dist/' + pkg.module` and `file: 'dist/' + pkg.main`

Comment: I tried to add `dist/` but no change :/

Comment: You need to uninstall and reinstall with `npm install`. And first ensure you that rollup create `dist/index.js` and `dist/index.es.js` files

Answer (score 1):

From the [NPM documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts), i understand that `prepare` is called with `npm install` without argument on a local environment.

Your `prepare` script calls `build` script then `build` script calls `rollup` command

Comment: Humm interesting.. I miss that part when a package is pack. I can see now what's calling the build when I install my dependencies.. But I still not understand why isn't running on my jenkins server ?